# Android HTTP Connection with Remote Database

Tags: android

I am having an Android Activity which I want to connect with MYSql database with JSP page as middle layer to accept values from android and do query on databse. 
Problem is I'm not able to send parameter values from Android Activity to JSP page. Application crashes as Emulator starts. I have given permission for internet in manifest file, This catches exception.

```
public void tryLogin() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");
        EditText etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        EditText etxt_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String username = etxt_user.getText().toString();
        String password = etxt_pass.getText().toString(); 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8084/authen/register.jsp");
        List< BasicNameValuePair > nvps = new ArrayList< BasicNameValuePair >();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
        try {
              UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps,"utf-8");

              httppost.setEntity(p_entity);

              HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
              Log.v(TAG, "Sahil Sahil Sahil");

              Log.v(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());
              HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
              Log.v(TAG, "Set response to responseEntity");

              SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
              SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
              XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
              LoginHandler myLoginHandler = new LoginHandler();

              xr.setContentHandler(myLoginHandler);
              xr.parse(retrieveInputStream(responseEntity));
              ParsedLoginDataSet parsedLoginDataSet = myLoginHandler.getParsedLoginData(); 
              if (parsedLoginDataSet.getExtractedString().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    // Store the username and password in SharedPreferences after the successful login
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=mPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("UserName", username);
                    editor.putString("PassWord", password);
                    editor.commit();
                    Message myMessage=new Message();
                    myMessage.obj="SUCCESS";
                    handler.sendMessage(myMessage); 
              } else if(parsedLoginDataSet.getExtractedString().equals("ERROR")) { 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginError.class);
                    intent.putExtra("LoginMessage", parsedLoginDataSet.getMessage());
                    startActivity(intent); 
                    removeDialog(0);
              } 
        } catch (Exception e) 
        { 
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginError.class);
              intent.putExtra("LoginMessage", "Unable to login");
              startActivity(intent);
              removeDialog(0);
        }
}
```

Comment: add some codes. what are the exceptions you are getting.

Comment: However, have an eye in LogCat. You will get some hint about the Error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a small example how to send parameters to a URL...

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
....
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("param1", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(param1, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param2", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(param2, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(http://example.com);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSP page that accepts an XML parameter in GET format, and do operation on that data.

Example:
You create a page like this, which will accept XML formatted data:

`http://example.com/api/getdb.jsp?data=XML_FORMATED_DATA`

Suppose you have the following XML data:

```
   String sXML = "<xml>" +
        "<table>" +
            "<row>" +
                "<name>Alice</name>" +
                "<salary>5000</salary>" +
            "</row>" +
            "<row>" +
                "<name>Bob</name>" +
                "<salary>7000</salary>" +
            "</row>" +
        "</table>" +
    "</xml>" ;
```

Now you just do this in your Android code:

```
String sUrlEncoded = UrlEncoder.encode(sXML, "utf-8"); // This line encodes XML symbols into URL-friendly characters.

URL url = new URL("http://example.com/api/getdb.jsp?data=" + sUrlEncoded);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

That's all...!

Now you've called your JSP page with the XML data as the GET parameter. In your JSP, you need to retrieve the XML data, and parse it, and perform the operation!

Just like: (I am trying some JSP!)

```
String pXML = request.getParameter("data");
// Now parse the content of pXML variable!
```

**Tip:**

**For added security, you can include a spot-generated session-key to the URL like this:**

`http://example.com/api/getdb.jsp?userid=USER_SESSION_KEY&data=XML_FORMATED_DATA`

Answer (score 0):

Working example from my code...

Android

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080//AddLocation.jsp");
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "007"));  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "James Bond");  
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

JSP

```
request.getParameter("id");
request.getParameter("name");
```